# How to detect if NSWindow is dragged?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, nswindow

I am using SwiftUI. I have a view called SideBar, that's consisting of VStack and buttons inside it.

I tried to attach some gestures, such as `DragGesture()` and `TapGesture()` `onended` on the VStack, hoping it would detect when a user drags the view, but this doesn't work all the time and I also think this is super hackish.

Would anyone be able to help? Thanks a lot.

Code:

```
VStack{blabla}

 .frame(width: 40, height: 320)

 .contentShape(Rectangle())

 .gesture(
   TapGesture().onEnded{_ in
     print("end click")
    }
  )

 .gesture(
   DragGesture().onEnded{_ in
    print("end drag")
   }
  )
```

Comment: It is not clear how the question's body relates to question's title. Do you want to drag entire window on drag in sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Just `DragGesture().onChanged(_:)` should suffice.
You can get the updated drag values, which you can decide how to use.

In the following example, when the `VStack` is dragged, the captured values re-renders the UI where it will be used to determine the `position` of the `VStack`.

#### Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World")
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .position(position)
        .gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged { (value) in
            self.position = CGPoint(x: value.location.x,
                                    y: value.location.y)
        })
    }
}
```